# ШнЫрять или шнырЯть?

Tags: этимология, фонетика

Во-первых, интересно само происхождения слова "шнырять",а во-вторых, как правильно ставить ударение: "шнЫрять" или "шнырЯть"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По Фасмеру:есть  шныря́ть - двигаться туда и сюда, в разных направлениях; сновать и шны́рить "исподтишка выслеживать, вынюхивать", шны́ра "соглядатай, тот, кто шныряет"
Звукоподражательного происхождения (Преобр., Труды I, 102). Можно говорить не об историческом, а самое большее – об "элементарном" родстве с нем. schnurren "жужжать, мурлыкать", ср.-в.-н. snurren "шуметь, свистеть", вопреки Гроту, (Фил. Раз. 1, 468), Горяеву (ЭС 424). http://vasmer.slovaronline.com/%D0%A8/%D0%A8%D0%9D/16541-SHNYIRYAT

Есть ещё профессионализм шны́рить - от ШНЫРЬ — подземный рабочий, работающий на поверхности (на-горах), получить что-нибудь на складе, подготовка оборудования и т. п. , что-то вроде каптёрщика
http://miningwiki.ru/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD

Есть жаргонное  шны́рить от Шнырь-заключенный,убирающий камеру, барак, производственное помещение в ШИЗО,  штаб, комнаты свиданий, отряды и т.п. http://prison.org/nravy/dictionary/sh.htm